# Shrink pandas Df by deleting rows through modulo

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to reduce (or select) for example multiple of 4 of the index.
i have a 2MS dataframe and i want to get less data for a future plot. so the idea is to work with 1/4 of the data. leaving only the rows with index 4 - 8 - 16 - 20 - 4*n (or maybe the same but with 5*n)
if someone has any idea i will be grateful.

Comment: Sorry are you asking for `df.iloc[::4]`?

Comment: You could also consider taking a subsample: df.sample(frac=0.25).
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `iloc` function, which takes a row/column slice.

From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

> Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position.
>
> .iloc[] is primarily integer position based (from 0 to length-1 of the
>   axis), but may also be used with a boolean array.

So you could write `df.iloc[::4, :]`